# MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer doesn't play some songs

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-musickit

I don't know what the issue is, I can't play any of the songs for Adele Essentials, https://itunes.apple.com/us/playlist/adele-essentials/pl.efaeab71d9cd4e079d9d1097c3b6b525

420075084 1051394215 420075185 1051394219 420075145 1051394224 1399800382 1051394813 420075085 1399799920 1051394223 1399800385 420075087 1051394227

Also from Lauren Daigle Essentials, I can play most songs but not all of them which is weird !

https://itunes.apple.com/au/playlist/lauren-daigle-essentials/pl.5972a5b59f294312a1c0365a88eefe28

They are both from the US store, I am in AU and I have music subscription.

I need to use MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer to stream songs from Apple Music Store

I'd love for someone senior who worked with MusicKit to shed some light please. Thank you.

```
appleMusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()

appleMusicPlayer?.setQueue(["420075084"])

appleMusicPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
```

This is with Swift 4 iOS 12 and Xcode 10.1 (10B61)

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, sorry I wasn't able to. If you come up with a solution to the root cause please let us know. Thanks

Comment: this may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736402/apple-music-kit-play-song-with-id-from-user-in-storefront-a-for-user-with-stor